# How can rendering faster in jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2, hdfs, fastapi

I use Fastapi and html(jinja2 template).

> First try, I rendering graph through plotly using "plotly.offline.plot".
>
> when i use "plotly.offline.plot", i can get rendering graph's plotly
> html string.
>
> and I send the rendered plotly graph html string using
> "templates.templateResponse".
>
> But it was very slowly.

therefore,I pre-save the rendered html string data in HDFS.

> I get the data that html data(saved through plotly or bokeh, etc...)
> from HDFS.
>
> and I send the rendered plotly graph html string using
> "templates.templateResponse".
>
> this rendering speed is very slow
> too.

What can i do this situation?
I need interaction graph, so i need to use plotly or bokeh, etc.

Comment: reduce number of points

Comment: @JoranBeasley If i cannot reduct number of points? is there a way?

Comment: if you only have 500 pixels of width you probably shouldnt have more than 500 datapoints ... although from my experience the graphing solution that can deal with the most points is canvasjs